# Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException: {"message":"2 errors occurred:\n\t* provisioning docker WSL distros: deploying

Tags: docker, windows

2 years cannot fix error install Docker on Windows

```
Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException:
{"message":"2 errors occurred:\n\t* provisioning docker WSL distros: deploying \"docker-desktop\": importing WSL distro \"docker-desktop\": deploying WSL distro \"docker-desktop\" (\"C:\\\\Program Files\\\\Docker\\\\Docker\\\\resources\\\\wsl\\\\wsl-bootstrap.tar\" -\u003e \"C:\\\\Users\\\\Administrator\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\Docker\\\\wsl\\\\distro\"): exit status 1\n\t* checking if isocache exists: CreateFile \\\\wsl$\\docker-desktop-data\\isocache\\: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.\n\n"}

   at Docker.Core.GoBackend.GoBackendClient.<PostNoBodyWithError>d__19.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\GoBackend\GoBackendClient.cs:line 226
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.WSL2.LinuxWSL2Engine.<DoStartAsync>d__11.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\WSL2\LinuxWSL2Engine.cs:line 54
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.TaskExtensions.<WrapAsyncInCancellationException>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\TaskExtensions.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 91
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.StartTransition.<DoRunAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\StartTransition.cs:line 118
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.ApiServices.StateMachines.EngineStateMachine.<StartAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.ApiServices\StateMachines\EngineStateMachine.cs:line 72
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Docker.Engines.Engines.<StartAsync>d__23.MoveNext() in C:\workspaces\4.16.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Engines\Engines.cs:line 109
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to resolve your issue

Uninstall Docker Desktop

Open Local Disk C

Navigate to Users<user name>\AppData\Roaming\Docker

Delete all files in the Docker folder

Reinstall the Docker application 4.15.0 version

Answer (score 0):

you could run `wsl --update` then on the cmd as admin `netsh winsock reset`
then restart the machine worked for me